# Postal code numbering adjacency problem

Tags: graph-theory

Please excuse me if this is a known problem.

After looking at a USPS map of postal codes I was curious whether it is possible to guarantee that given a $2$-dimensional map of regions where each region is assigned a unique number, can it be guaranteed that at least one adjacent region has a sequential number either ascending or descending

So for instance, assign the first region a number such as $100$, then an adjacent region either $99$ or $101$, then adjacent to that $\pm 1$ whatever you've chosen and so on.

This might be related to TSP or $4$ color. I'm pretty sure $\pm\{1,2\}$ is pretty easy to demonstrate as always possible but I'm not confident on $\pm 1$.

Note: I'm an amateur mathematician, please excuse me for any formalism issues

Comment: I think your question is equivalent to asking whether a certain graph has a Hamiltonian path, the graph formed by taking each region of the map as a vertex with two regions connected if and only if they are adjacent. So you might learn something of interest to you by reading about Hamiltonian paths. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path

Comment: @Will, I think not. Consider the five-vertex graph with vertices $a,b,c,d,e$ and edges $ab, ac, ad, de$. No Hamiltonian path, but you can number the vertices $2,1,3,4,5$.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen: You're right! So having a Hamiltonian path is sufficient, but not necessary, for there to be a numbering like the OP describes.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen: An even easier example to show this, if you don't require the graph to be connected (an Alaska/Hawaii sort of situation) is just to take the disjoint union of two maps that each admit a "good" numbering.

Answer (score 10):

If there are four regions, three of which border the fourth but don't share a border with each other, then it's easy to see that there can't be any such numbering.

EDIT ––– I'm beginning to think this example may be, in essence, the only way a map can fail to have the sort of numbering requested. First, as usual, let's replace our map with a (necessarily planar) graph that has a vertex for each region, and an edge joining two vertices if and only if the two corresponding regions share a border.

If there is a vertex adjacent to three (or more) vertices of degree one (that is to say, if there is a region $X$ having three or more neighbors, each of which has only region $X$ as a neighbor), then it is clearly impossible to give different numbers to each of these vertices of degree one in such a way as to give each of them a number sequential to that given to their only neighbor, $X$.

So, we have a simple sufficient condition for the non-existence of a sequential numbering (or, to put a positive spin on it, a simple necessary condition for there to be a sequential numbering). I have not been able to find a graph where every vertex is adjacent to at most two vertices of degree one, which nevertheless fails to have a sequential numbering; neither can I prove there is no such graph.

MORE EDIT --- sorry, I found a very simple example of what I thought might not exist, namely, the following graph of seven vertices, two of which are adjacent to exactly two vertices of degree one, the graph having no sequential numbering (apologies for the childish drawing):

$$\matrix{\bullet A&&&&\bullet E\cr
\mid&&&&\mid\cr
\bullet B&--&\bullet D&--&\bullet F\cr
\mid&&&&\mid\cr
\bullet C&&&&\bullet G}
$$

So, we're back to square one. We have a simple result in one direction, but not even a conjecture in the converse direction.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The answer is clear and answers the question definitively.

Comment: @Jukka, one person has voted to close the question, perhaps that person thought the question was of a type that shouldn't be answered. Or perhaps the downvoter thought I went for the low-hanging fruit instead of trying to give necessary and sufficient conditions for the numbering to be possible. Or, perhaps someone's finger just slipped.

Comment: Gerry, indeed, it could be any of those. I just hope it is not the first option. It would be a shame if MO fell into the "punitive downvotes on good answers to questions I don't like" practice that is so common on Math.SE.

Comment: @Jukka, I am pleased to report that just today I received an "undownvote", so all is well.

Answer (score 3):

The property you ask (for an arbitrary graph $G$) is equivalent to having a collection $\{P_1, \dotsc, P_k\}$ of vertex-disjoint paths, each with at least one edge, which cover all vertices of your desired graph $G$.
Let me say this is a *strong path-partition*
(Without the extra requirement of all paths having at least one edge, this is known in the literature as a *path-partition* of the graph $G$, but I am not aware if this stronger version has a name, and I just made one up.)

Indeed, if $G$ has a strong path-partition, we can just fix an orientation of each path and order the vertices of $G$ first including all vertices of $P_1$ in the chosen order, then all vertices of $P_2$, and so on; and label the vertices in that order. Since all vertices have at least one neighbour in one of the paths $P_i$, this ordering will ensure they get one label which is a succesor or predecessor to its own label. For the other direction, take a labelling of $V(G)$ with the property you described and form a subgraph $H$ by including an edge $xy$ only if their labels are consecutive. This will give a spanning subgraph where every vertex is contained in an edge, without cycles, and of maximum degree at most two, so indeed it is a collection of paths as described.

As noted by some other comments, having a Hamiltonian path is enough to have a strong path-partition; but it is not necessary: e.g. a perfect matching would also work just as fine.

Since you ask for "maps" it is also reasonable to see if something more can be said if the graph $G$ is assumed to be planar. I do not have an answer to this. As pointed out in the other answers, there are even trees which do not admit a strong path-partition.
I only have a few observations:

1. A graph with a strong path-partition cannot contain three leaves adjacent to the same vertex (since those edges need to be covered by paths). If two leaves $u, v$ are adjacent with the same vertex $x$ then $uxv$ is the only possible path to cover those leaves, so we can remove $uxv$ and the graph $G$ will have a strong path-partition if and only if $G - uxv$ has one.
2. Also if $G$ is connected and bipartite and has a strong path-partition, it cannot be that one part is more than double the size of the other (since the most imbalanced path has two vertices in one side and one in the other). Thus a complete bipartite graph $K_{2, r}$ with $r \geq 5$ is an example of a planar graph which does not have a strong path-partition.